# Calling cURL from android application

Tags: java, android, http, curl, https

I am trying to call CURL because I need a quick and dirty way to ignore a self signed SSL certificate and I can't find any suitably quick and dirty ways in java alone.

This is the function I am currently using:

```
public String httpRequest(String httpsUrl) {
    String ret;

    // all of the java based HTTP requests are **** so here is cURL to the rescue
    try {
        // Process curl = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/curl --insecure '" + httpsUrl + "'");
        String cmdString[] = {"/system/bin/curl", "--insecure", httpsUrl};

        Process curl = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdString);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(curl.getInputStream()));

        curl.waitFor();

        String line = ret = in.readLine();

        while ( line != null ) {
            ret += line + "\n";
            line = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The exact problem that I am having is that it isn't doing... anything.
It doesn't make the request it doesn't throw any exceptions and it has no output. If I just run "/system/bin/curl --help" it works fine and returns the help page, if I copy the log from the log in Android Studio and run it manually from a terminal it works fine, but for some reason its just failing silently.

The pages I am trying to request are just JSON generated from a nodejs script and reverse proxied through a lighttpd web server and this is all just for a private project, I would very much like to get this app out of the way as quickly as possible as its only a small part of the project and the only bit in a language I am not familiar with.

Comment: https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/making-android-ssl-work-correctly has a detailed description for making a hostnameverifier and a trusmanager to handle the problem.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code with breakpoints?